# Unable to perform segue due to no segue with identifier error

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

How can I do so the user gets taken to a custom view controller when he/she taps on "okay" button on alert?

I have a main controller -> navigation controller -> second view controller.

Main View Controller has a segue "mainStoryBoard"
The alert gets generated on the second view controller.

This is what I have

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message",     preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action
    in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainStoryBoard", sender: self)
}))

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
return
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'mainStoryBoard'

I have set the identifier to 'mainStoryBoard' and still no luck.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What issues are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: @rmaddy I am getting - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<udidtoolapp.Setup: 0x1014684b0>) has no segue with identifier 'mainStoryBoard''`

Comment: Make sure you have given the segue an identifier EXACTLY equal to "mainStoryBoard"

Comment: Perhaps [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+NSInvalidArgumentException+has+no+segue+with+identifier) will help.

Comment: Are you sure you set it properly? You clicked on the segue and then went to the attributes inspector and filled in the "identifier" field with "mainStoryBoard" (case sensitive)?

Comment: @MikeG yes that is exactly what I did.

Comment: Are you trying to segue from SecondViewController to MainViewController? did you drag the segue in this order as well? or perhaps did you drag the segue from MainViewController to SecondViewController?

Comment: @MikeG that was the problem. I had to drag it from Second to Main controller... but now I do not see the navigation bar on the main controller. any clues?

Comment: @MikeG I figured it out. thanks for you guidance

Comment: cool glad to hear

Comment: @rob - your problem is solved or not

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your storyboard please? @rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MikeG's guidance I was able to get it to work.

The problem was that I created a segue from the `main view controller` to the `second view controller`.

**Solution**

Create a `segue` from the `second view controller` to the `main view controller` and if you have a `navigation controller`, create the segue from the `second view controller` to the `navigation controller`.

The code remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading your main view controller?. Try to instantiate using instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier not with alloc init. Still if you are facing this problem then try to clean the project and run.